# How could I fix Remote access to a shared hosting mysql database refused

Tags: mysql, cpanel, remote-access, vps, csf

I have a database in a shared hosting website xxx.com and a vps aaa.xxx.com that access to that database.

in the website cpanel I added the ip of the vps in the remote mysql page and it was working until I installed CSF in the vps. Now it gives me a "Connection refused".

What should I undo in order to make everyting work again. I apreciate your help. thank you.

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Contact your hosting provider. That's what you're paying them for.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding the database ip adress in the allow section of csf